# Why strcmp does not return 0?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strcmp

I have a small program to handle a list of rabbits (name, district, participation count) stored in an array of pointers (Rabbit** iterator). I'd like to implement the following methods: add, delete and modify a rabbit, list all the rabbits or list by district.

When I compare for example the name of the rabbits in the list with strcmp() it doesn't return 0 when the names are equal. How can I solve this problem?

The Rabbit struct:

```
typedef struct Rabbit {
    char* name;
    char* district;
    unsigned part_count;
} Rabbit;
```

The delete method:

```
bool delete_rabbit(char* delete_name)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (iterator[i] != NULL && strcmp(iterator[i]->name, delete_name) == 0) {
            free(iterator[i]);
            iterator[i] = NULL;
            count--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The list by district method:

```
void list_by_district(char* district)
{
    unsigned counter = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (iterator[i] != NULL && strcmp(iterator[i]->district, district) == 0) {
            counter++;
            printf("\n%u. Rabbit:\n", counter);
            printf("Name: %s\nDistrict: %s\nParticipation count: %u\n", iterator[i]->name, iterator[i]->district, iterator[i]->part_count);
        }
    }
}
```

The modify method is similar to the delete method except it only changes the values.

The corresponding code snippets from main:

```
Rabbit** iterator;
unsigned size = 10, count = 0;
int main()
{
    iterator = (Rabbit**)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit*) * 10);
    ...
    do {
        ...
        switch (input) {
            case 'a':
                if (count == size) iterator = allocate_more_memory();
                ...
                iterator[count++] = add_rabbit(new_name, new_district, new_part_count);
                break;
            case 'd':
                if (size == count + 6) iterator = allocate_less_memory();
                do {
                    printf("Enter name to be deleted: ");
                    scanf("%[^\n]", delete_name);
                    getchar();
                    if (strlen(delete_name) >= 30) printf("Name only has 30 or less characters!\n");
                } while (strlen(delete_name) >= 30);
                if (!delete_rabbit(delete_name)) printf("\nThere's no rabbit in the list with this name.\n");
                break;
            ...
        }
    } while (input != 'x');  
    ...
    free(iterator);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

The add method:

```
Rabbit* add_rabbit(char* new_name, char* new_district, unsigned new_part_count)
{
    Rabbit* new_rabbit = (Rabbit*)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit));
    if (new_rabbit) {
        new_rabbit->name = (char*)malloc((strlen(new_name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        new_rabbit->district = (char*)malloc((strlen(new_district) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(new_rabbit->name, new_name);
        strcpy(new_rabbit->district, district);
        new_rabbit->part_count = new_part_count;
    }
    return new_rabbit;
}
```

The allocate less memory method:

```
Rabbit** allocate_less_memory()
{
    Rabbit** new_iterator = (Rabbit**)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit*) * (size - 5));
    if (new_iterator) {
        unsigned counter = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if (iterator[i] != NULL) {
                new_iterator[counter++] = iterator[i];
            }
        }
        size -= 5;
        free(iterator);
        return new_iterator;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that `strcmp` is buggy, so I'd suspect your data (or user input) is at fault... You should probably show how you're allocating those Rabbits and entering their data.

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` would scan any whitespace, too. Have you considered that?

Comment: How is `delete_name` defined? How are you going to make sure the user cannot input more characters than the buffer provides?

Comment: When you print your message that the input is too long, you have already read too many characters and corrupted your surronding memory. You should limit `scanf` to read only 29 characters: `"%29[^\n]"`

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` is unsafe. Better to use `fgets()` and then check that the read string ends with a `'\n'`. If not, read and discard the remainder of the line with a `getchar()` loop and complain that the input was too long. Otherwise, replace the `'\n'` at the end of the string with a `'\0'` null terminator.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including one sequence of code (not separate listings of isolated functions; one complete listing that can be compiled and executed) that reproduces the problem with no changes or additions, an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, the observed output or behavior, and the desired output or behavior instead. The complete listing generally should not be your complete program but should be reduced to just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `if (strlen(delete_name) >= 30)` is likely off by 1.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the strlen(delete_name) is working well, for example for this name: "Hering Herold" it returns 13.

Comment: @Gerhardh so if I use "%29[^\n]" the if(strlen(name)>=30) and the while loop are not necessary?

Comment: @ZoltánOrosz That `while` loop is not needed as the read portion of input will not be too long, yet other code useful to cope with potential excessive long input remaining in `stdin`.

Comment: In both `if` and `while` conditions, the expression will always be `false`. if you limit the input accordingly. You can remove them but as chux mentioned, excess characters will stay in the buffer and you should take care of them.